Are there memory leaks in the glibc fdopen implementation?
The source code is here: https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/libio/iofdopen.c
As shown in the iofdopen.c , line 122 of the code creates a new_f object with malloc
new_f = (struct locked_FILE *) malloc (sizeof (struct locked_FILE));

but it does not call free(new_f) before returns as line 159
/* For append mode, set the file offset to the end of the file if we added
   O_APPEND to the file descriptor flags.  Don't update the offset cache
   though, since the file handle is not active.  */
if (do_seek && ((read_write & (_IO_IS_APPENDING | _IO_NO_READS))
    == (_IO_IS_APPENDING | _IO_NO_READS)))
{
    off64_t new_pos = _IO_SYSSEEK (&new_f->fp.file, 0, _IO_seek_end);
    if (new_pos == _IO_pos_BAD && errno != ESPIPE)
        return NULL;
}

Is there a memory leak bug here?

Does this answer your question? POSIX fdopen() function in C

Considering that the function ends with return &new_f->fp.file; it looks like a leak. And it becomes even worse considering that fclose basically ends with a free(fp), where fp is the pointer returned by fdopen. I don't think the glibc authors are that stupid, so there's likely something else going on. I recommend you to step through the code in a debugger if you really want to know what's going on.

@Someprogrammerdude I haven't looked at the structures but would guess that fp is the first element of locked_FILE and file is the first element of the the structure which is the type of new_f->fp. Then the pointers would basically be the same

@IngoLeonhardt It's indeed true, and something I overlooked. So no memory leaks for the success-case. But there is for the failure case being asked about.

@simonzgx your last code snippet doesn't make sense as fopen() already returns a FILE * and if you used open() instead you had to use close() instead of fclose() and no FILE * would be freed there. So I think that yes: if the error condition that leads to the returnin line 159 really occurs, fdopen() leaves a leak. But that should be very rare cases

@Ingo Leonhardt Yes that was a mistake. It should be if (fdopen(fd, "w") == nullptr){close(fd);}.
And thank you for your reply, I will take some time to look into this, and if there is any progress, I will leave a comment here.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not really a question. OP gave the answer already. This sounds like a bug report for a third-party library to me. Nice catch, but not really an on-topic Stack Overflow question IMHO. (NB: to be an on-topic question about the code, the full (relevant) code should be included here, not by linking to an external site)

It looks like OP is correct is suspecting a memory leak. There does seem to be one.
Test program on Linux with /dev/mem support (the /dev/mem file does not support seeking relative to the end of the file):
dev-mem-append.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{
    int memfd;
    FILE *fpmem;

    memfd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
    if (memfd == -1)
    {
        perror("/dev/mem");
        printf("No need to check for memory leak in fdopen()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fpmem = fdopen(memfd, "a");
    if (fpmem == NULL)
    {
        perror("fdopen");
        printf("Please check for memory leak in fdopen()\n");
        close(memfd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("fdopen succeeded. No need to check for memory leak.\n");
    fclose(fpmem);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

Compiling:
$ gcc -O2 dev-mem-append.c -o dev-mem-append

Running with sudo:
$ sudo ./dev-mem-append
fdopen: Invalid argument
Please check for memory leak in fdopen()

Running with sudo and valgrind:
$ sudo valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./dev-mem-append
==232== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==232== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==232== Using Valgrind-3.16.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==232== Command: ./dev-mem-append
==232==
fdopen: Invalid argument
Please check for memory leak in fdopen()
==232==
==232== HEAP SUMMARY:
==232==     in use at exit: 472 bytes in 1 blocks
==232==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 3 frees, 2,992 bytes allocated
==232==
==232== 472 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==232==    at 0x483877F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==232==    by 0x48C61E0: fdopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofdopen.c:122)
==232==    by 0x1090DE: main (in /home/testuser/dev-mem-append)
==232==
==232== LEAK SUMMARY:
==232==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==232==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==232==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==232==    still reachable: 472 bytes in 1 blocks
==232==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==232==
==232== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==232== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

This has been reported as a bug at Sourceware Bugzilla: Bug #31840.

funny that it's 'still reachable' so there must be some reference to new_f somewhere that is not obvious from the source - at least to me

@IngoLeonhardt I was wondering about the same thing!

@IngoLeonhardt open FILEs are flushed and closed at normal program exit, so there's probably still a reference to it somewhere because of that.

@Shawn That makes sense! I think that is done by the call to _IO_link_in from _IO_new_file_init_internal from _IO_new_fdopen.
